# How to resolve 'getUserByAccount is not a function' in next-auth?

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

I've updated Nextjs to it's newest version and also updated next-auth and the prisma adapter as specified by the docs.

However, when I try to authenticate in the app with `signIn` I get the following error with the latest updates:

```
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error getUserByAccount is not a function {
  message: 'getUserByAccount is not a function',
  stack: 'TypeError: getUserByAccount is not a function\n' +
    '    at Object.callback (/home/.../node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:81:39)\n' +
    '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)\n' +
    '    at async NextAuthHandler (/home/.../node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:103:28)\n' +
    '    at async NextAuthNextHandler (/home/.../node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:40:7)\n' +
    '    at async [...]/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:80:32\n' +
    '    at async Object.apiResolver (/home/.../node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils.js:102:9)\n' +
    '    at async DevServer.handleApiRequest (/home/.../node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1014:9)\n' +
    '    at async Object.fn (/home/.../node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:901:37)\n' +
    '    at async Router.execute (/home/.../node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:210:32)',
  name: 'TypeError'
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there an incompatibility I'm missing?

Relevant `package.json`:

```
...
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^0.5.2-next.19",
    "next": "^12.0.3",
    "next-auth": "4.0.0-beta.6",
    "prisma": "^3.4.1",
...
```

`[...nextauth].ts`:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CognitoProvider from 'next-auth/providers/cognito';
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    CognitoProvider({
      clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.COGNITO_ISSUER,
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, user }) {
      session.userId = user.id;
      session.role = user.role;
      return Promise.resolve(session);
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally resolved the problem. Since next-auth has moved to monorepo, updating package was not enough, you need to uninstall it first then install it again.

Run:

```
npm uninstall next-auth @next-auth/prisma-adapter
```

then:

```
npm install @next-auth/prisma-adapter
```

This fixed it for me.

Comment: Now it's npm install @auth/prisma-adapter

Answer (score 3):

In the NextAuth.JS 4.0 the "Prisma schema" have slightly changed.

From the [upgrade guide](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/upgrade-v4#schema-changes):

> - `created_at`/`createdAt` and `updated_at`/`updatedAt` fields are removed from all Models.
> - `user_id`/`userId` consistently named `userId`.
> - `compound_id`/`compoundId` is removed from Account.
> - `access_token`/`accessToken` is removed from Session.
> - `email_verified`/`emailVerified` on User is consistently named `email_verified`.
> - `provider_id`/`providerId` renamed to provider on Account
> - `provider_type`/`providerType` renamed to type on Account
> - `provider_account_id`/`providerAccountId` on Account is consistently named `providerAccountId`
> - `access_token_expires`/`accessTokenExpires` on Account renamed to `expires_in`
> - New fields on Account: `expires_at`, `token_type`, `scope`, `id_token`, `session_state`
> - `verification_requests` table has been renamed to `verification_tokens`

Complete new schema in:
https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/prisma

Answer (score 2):

my version:
"@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.5",
"next-auth": "^4.21.1",

i have resolved the error, uninstall @next-auth/prisma-adapter next-auth, and install @next-auth/prisma-adapter next-auth again

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure you get matching versions of these packages or issues will arise.

Answer (score 0):

I used   "debug:process.env.NODE_ENV ==='development'", and worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the following:

```bash
$ npm uninstall next-auth @next-auth/prisma-adapter
$ npm install @next-auth/prisma-adapter next-auth
```